# If I want to make a new table for Wordpress, do I prefix it with "wp_"?

Tags: wordpress, database-design, upload

I noticed that all of the tables in PHPMyAdmin start with "wp_". I want to make a new table to populate with user uploaded images *tied to their posts*, so can I just name it anything or is it necessary to name it with "wp_"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you? Yes. Should you? No! It's a good practice to use the common prefix for any custom tables.

The table prefix (`wp_` by default) is set in your wp-config.php file. Users have the ability to change this prefix themselves.

You'll want to create the table using the same prefix and then take advantage of the database class in WordPress.  For instance if you name your table `wp_user_images` you could refer to it with `$wpdb->prefix . 'user_images'` (making sure you have access to the wpdb global first).

Also keep in mind that if you're writing code which you plan to distribute you'll need to create the tables programmatically. Some users may have multiple installations of WordPress in a single database with different prefixes providing separation. If one of those users ran your code they would have multiple sites sharing a single table.